# How to write a string representing a card for GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface

I'm writing a card game program in Python and I want the GUI to display all the cards in a hand.

```
suits = ['spades','hearts','diamonds','clubs']
ranks = ['ace','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten','jack','queen','king']

def create_deck():
    deck = []
    for suit in suits:
        for rank in ranks:
            deck.append((suit,rank))
    return deck

def shuffle(deck):
    for i in range(100):
        card = deck.pop(randint(0,51)) 
        deck.append(card)

values = {}
i = 1
for card in deck:
    values[card]=i
    if i == 13:
        i = 1
    else:
        i += 1
print values #dictionary mapping values to cards
```

I want a function that writes a string representing each card in a hand, which I believe can be done by iterating a function that writes a string representing each card over each card in the hand. However, I'm not really sure what it should look like (i.e. if I need parameters for the function, if the parameters should be 'suit, rank', or simply 'card', etc.).

Comment: possible duplicate of [python only show tuple items in loop x amount of times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459803/python-only-show-tuple-items-in-loop-x-amount-of-times)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> my_hand = [('spades','ace'), ('hearts','five'), ('hearts','six')]
>>> def showhand(hand):
...     return '\n'.join([rank.title() + ' of ' + suit.title() for (suit,rank) in hand])
...
>>> print(showhand(my_hand))
Ace of Spades
Five of Hearts
Six of Hearts
```